# .strip not working in python

Tags: python, string, strip

I don't really understand the .strip function.

Say I have a string

```
xxx = 'hello, world'
```

and I want to strip the comma.
Why doesn't

```
print xxx.strip(',')
```

work?

Comment: please read the documentation. `strip` works, it just does not do what you want it to do. use `replace` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`str.strip()` removes characters from the *start and end of a string only*. From the [`str.strip()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> Return a copy of the string with the **leading and trailing characters** removed.

Emphasis mine.

Use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to remove text from everywhere in the string:

```
xxx.replace(',', '')
```

For a *set* of characters use a regular expression:

```
import re

re.sub(r'[,!?]', '', xxx)
```

Demo:

```
>>> xxx = 'hello, world'
>>> xxx.replace(',', '')
'hello world'
```

Answer (score 7):

[`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes characters from the beginning or end of the string, not in the middle.

```
>>> ',hello, world,'.strip(',')
'hello, world'
```

If you want remove character from everywhere, you should use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) instead:

```
>>> 'hello, world'.replace(',', '')
'hello world'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the **translate** method of the *string* class.  If you pass in **None** for the table parameter, then only the character deletion step is executed.

```
>>> 'hello, world'.translate(None,',')
'hello world'
```